# running .mat with octvae error "nested function is not implemented in this context"

Tags: python-3.x, matlab, octave, google-colaboratory, matconvnet

I am running matconvnet file with .m extension in google colab using octave

when i ran the command using the using the octave i got the follwoing error

command

```
 !octave -W /content/drive/MyDrive/matconv/matconvnet-1.0-beta18/matlab/vl_compilenn.m
```

error

```
 parse error near line 459 of file /content/drive/MyDrive/matconv/matconvnet-1.0- 
 beta18/matlab/vl_compilenn.m

    nested functions not implemented in this context

 >>> function objs = toobj(bld_dir,srcs)
       ^

  error: source: error sourcing file '/content/drive/MyDrive/matconv/matconvnet-1.0-beta18/matlab/vl_compilenn.m'
```

Please help me how to resolve this error

Comment: A [nested function](https://octave.org/doc/v5.2.0/Nested-Functions.html) is a function appearing within a function. It appears either colab or octave does not know how to handle those in the particular way the script is attempting to use them. You could move that function out of the primary one, make it a [subfunction](https://octave.org/doc/v5.2.0/Subfunctions.html#Subfunctions). One thing to note is that if the nested function relies on accessing variables defined in the primary function, you'll have to pass those explicitly to the subfunction you create.

Comment: Also, to state the "obvious", all this assumes the file you are using is compatible with octave to begin with. If it is a matlab file, especially one that relies on lots of external toolboxes, it is unlikely that it can be run 'out of the box' in an octave environment (at least not without heavy modification).

Comment: Perhaps a better question might be, why are you trying to run this on google colab with octave? If what you have is a matlab file and you want a shareable report, perhaps you could try matlab publisher, or matlab live scripts instead?

Comment: thankyou , but i need a nvidia gpu to run the object detcteion quickly, and nvidia gpu is not given by matlab live scripsts